# Using google test on windows with MSVC 2015

Tags: c++, testing, googletest

I have spent far too long trying to get GoogleTest working using MSVC 2015 so I'm hoping you clever SO guys can give me a hand.

What I've done:

1. Cloned the GoogleTest github repo to my machine.
2. Used CMake to generate MSVC project files. (I originally used the project files that come with the checkout, only to later find out after some searching that these do not appear to be complete and the CMake generated ones have apparently the correct defines etc

I can see that the sample tests compile fine in the CMake generate projects. However, on the project I have created for my own tests this is not the case. I've looked up just about every SO thread I can find and any other nuget of info... I have also made sure that between the CMake sample tests projects and my own that all the compiler and linker options are identical, so I'm at a total loss.

In my project I get the following compilation errros

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2440   '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'testing::internal::AssertHelper'    TestMpegMessing C:\Users\James\Documents\Git\mpeg_ts_messing\gtest\src\gtest_binary_buffer.cpp  6   
Error   C2065   'gtest_ar': undeclared identifier   TestMpegMessing C:\Users\James\Documents\Git\mpeg_ts_messing\gtest\src\gtest_binary_buffer.cpp  6   
Error   C2589   'switch': illegal token on right side of '::'   TestMpegMessing C:\Users\James\Documents\Git\mpeg_ts_messing\gtest\src\gtest_binary_buffer.cpp  6   
Error   C2181   illegal else without matching if    TestMpegMessing C:\Users\James\Documents\Git\mpeg_ts_messing\gtest\src\gtest_binary_buffer.cpp  6   
Error   C2228   left of '.failure_message' must have class/struct/union TestMpegMessing C:\Users\James\Documents\Git\mpeg_ts_messing\gtest\src\gtest_binary_buffer.cpp  6   
Error   C2059   syntax error: '::'  TestMpegMessing C:\Users\James\Documents\Git\mpeg_ts_messing\gtest\src\gtest_binary_buffer.cpp  6
```

Has anyone had a similar problem? If not, I could do with a few tips on how on earth to further debug this.

Comment: Have you added required library file to your project and the required headers.

Answer (score 0):

right click on your project select properties.
select c/c++  -> general -> Additional include directories

the path for example would be

```
E:\googletest-master\googletest-master\googletest\include;
```

Linker  -> general
Additional library directories

```
E:\googletest-master\googletest-master\googletest\msvc\gtest\Debug
```

Linker -> input 
add the following

```
gtestd.lib
gtest_maind.lib
```

C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library

```
Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)
```

this is for 32 bit debug. you will need to setup for 32 bit release, 64 bit debug and 64 bit release.

Test code i used

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "math.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double squareroot(const double x)
{
    return sqrt(x);
};

TEST(SquareRootTest, PositiveNos) {
    EXPECT_EQ(18.0, squareroot(324.0));
    EXPECT_EQ(25.4, squareroot(645.16));
    EXPECT_EQ(50.3321, squareroot(2533.310224));
}

TEST(SquareRootTest, ZeroAndNegativeNos) {
    ASSERT_EQ(0.0, squareroot(0.0));
    ASSERT_EQ(-1, squareroot(-22.0));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);

    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but alas I already have my setup like this (I had double checked against the CMake generated projects), hence my problem...

Comment: did you successfully build the libraries?

Comment: Yep sure, will have to do it this evening though. Thanks again.